# Cast Colored light on white surface

Tags: rendering, lighting, color

Hej !

Does anybody have a trick to cast a coloured light on a white surface in a stronger way than a pale color ? I want to casted color to be like on the second picture but on a surface like the first picture.
Being unrealistic i don't know if there is a way, but maybe anybody has a idea ? I've been trying for a while but never got satisfiying results

Any hints of suggestion appreciated !

Best

[image]
[image]